# How to list all files under an object

Tags: python, minio

I have a bucket and inside it I have my object that is a folder. And inside this folder there are many files. How can I list all these files under my `object_name` in single request? I try this `my_list = my_object_name/*.csv` But it doesn't work

```
client = Minio(xxxx)    
bucket_name = 'xxxxx'
list_files = 'object_name/*.csv'
obj = client.get_object(bucket_name, list_files)
```

Could you please help to get all files under my object (a folder)?